# OpenGL ES 2.0 Program Flow

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to understand where the shaders run in a basic OpenGL program.  I know the shader program is running on the video card, so I guess it's in parallel with the main loop.  But I'd like to understand where the links occur between the two.  Here's my Draw function:

```
void Draw(ESContext *esContext)
{
    GLfloat vVertices[] = {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                          -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                           0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f};


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    eglSwapBuffers(esContext->eglDisplay, esContext->eglSurface);
}
```

Does the shader program run the first time right after glDrawArrays is called?  Also, is it going to keep looping through and processing those same 3 vertices even if my main loop stalls out for a few ms?  What I mean is, will the video card keep looping through and processing those 3 verts until it receives a new instruction, or will it process them once and then wait for another call from glDrawArrays or a similar command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the shader program will execute some short time after the first call to glDrawArrays.
- No, it does not continue looping. It will draw what you have queued (in your case one triangle) to the active framebuffer, then continue working on any other queued work, then idle until the next instruction is received.